# flatlist pagination make app really slow on android

Tags: react-native

i am using a flat list for rendering data from server but the problem i have is when i render lots of data my app become too much slow

```
 <FlatList
      data={this.state.product}
      numColumns={2}
      inverted
      renderItem={({item}) =>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.homeGride}>
        <View style={styles.offer}>
        <Text style={styles.offerText}>{item.offer}%</Text>
        </View>
        <ImageBackground style={styles.homeImage} source={{uri:`${item.img}`}}>

        </ImageBackground>
        <Text style={styles.homeProductText}>{item.title}</Text>
        <View style={{flexDirection:"row-reverse"}}>
        <Text style={{flex:1,fontFamily:"FaNum"}}>{item.price}</Text>
        <Text style={{flex:1,fontFamily:"FaNum"}}>{item.new_price}</Text>
        </View>
        <Button small danger>
          <Text style={{padding:5}}>خرید</Text>
        </Button>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      }  
      keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

you should consider using `onEndReached` attribute of FlatList.
first define a `page` state

```
this.setState({page:1});
```

when fetching data from server send `page` parms to chunk the data
for Ex. in laravel server side framework do this :

```
$data = Data::where("sth","sth")->paginate(10,'page');
```

now in your react native application :

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.product}
  numColumns={2}
  inverted
  onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
  onEndThreshold={10}
  renderItem={({item}) =>
    ..sth..
  }  
  keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
  />
```

now in handleLoadMore add 1 number to `page` state and again fetch data
this will help you improve your speed and performance and fetch other data when they are needed !

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the [recyclerListView component](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview)
it has better performance for android devices.